# ZingTouch: How to call different URLs with both mouse and finger swipe gestures

Tags: javascript, php, css, responsive, swipe

I want to implement a method to call a next or previous page (i.e. different URLs) via mouse or finger gesture.

Last year, I implemented a solution with `jquery` and `jquery mobile`, but this did not satisfy me. ZingTouch looks promising, but their `Swipe` gesture does not provide `swipeleft` or `swiperight` methods.

That said, I cannot find out what to do with any of their methods. A code example would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a very helpful example in a closed issue of `ZingTouch`:  https://github.com/zingchart/zingtouch/issues/14 which immediately led to the solution (kudos to **markadrake** and mike-schultz).

### TL;DR

The key is to use `Pan`, not `Swipe`, and work with `angle`.

```
let angle = e.detail.data[0].directionFromOrigin;
```

I wouldn't know what to do with `e.detail.data` to begin with, so I guess I had no chance to find the solution myself.

#### Full example

In order to understand the whole process and show responsive image design as well, I will elaborate.

**Responsive image design with swiping via mouse or finger to call next/previous**

Every page I want to swipe through has a prominent image at top. This image is resized automatically to best fit with respect to the viewport and will resize if the viewport is resized.

Swiping this image to the left or right with mouse or finger should call the next or previous pages. This is the problem to be solved.

**CSS**

```
.responsive {
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:87vh;
}
```

This is the trigger for the browser to do the magic and resize the image as seen fit.

**PHP**

In this project from 2007, I have a general function `img($path, $url='', $scale='')`  which produces the html code for all images. It takes as parameters the image path `$path` and eventually a `$url` to make it clickable and invoke another page.

As seen, I originally implemented a scaling function, but we can do better today. The changes to the original code are minimal.

**Add responsive image design**

The pages in question all use a global variable `$single` which contains the ID of the main image. This ID is also the `path` of the `URL`.

`$single` is used to implement `responsive` to the right *img html*, not to the plethora of other images on the page (`wp_sp` is just a lazy helper function for `strpos` to care for the `0` / `false` discrimination):

```
$responsive = $single           # we look for a page having a main image (there are many others with images)
    && wp_sp($path, $single)    # this function call is for the image we look for, not for others on this page
        ? " class='responsive' "
        : '';
```

Hence if `$responsive` is not empty, we classify the image to be enhanced with that swiping functionality with `class` `responsive`.

Also we need to make sure the dimensions of the image are the best possible we have for responsive adaption: `$path_1600` is the variant of `$path` (i.e. image path given) pointing to the large version of the image, having `1600px` width.

```
$dim = getImageSize($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . substr($path_1600, 1));
```

This variable `$responsive` is added to the `HTML` code, empty or not:

```
$img = "<img src='$path' "
        . str_replace('"', "'", $dim[3])
        . $responsive
        . " border=0 alt='$altText'>";
```

That HTML snippet in combination with CSS takes care for the reponsive presentation of the main image.

Magic! Just great! Problem solved where it should be: at the browser level. No more clumsy workarounds and costly artificial scaling.

Now this image has to be stuffed with swipe functionality.

**Add swiping**

In order to know where that swipe functionality should trigger, I use a `div` for images qualifying for swiping, i.e. our main image only:

```
if ($responsive) {
    $img = "<div id='swipe_here'>$img</div>";
}
```

The following code is from `footer.php` and implements this functionality elegantly to that div `swipe_here` by way of `ZingTouch`.

`$n` and `$p` are the IDs of the next or previous images, being the `path` of the URL, so redirection is easy with `Javascript`:

```
echo '
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zingtouch/1.0.6/zingtouch.min.js" integrity="sha512-HmaXasRYOQJEXJWYwYCMcIA/XnPtW9WPvaBVWE2mQP6K31sRdcgaYUyB//P5540J4hFqMBcj6vkDEEGkwHkYdA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
var zt = new ZingTouch.Region(document.body);
var myElement = document.getElementById("swipe_here");
zt.bind(myElement, "pan", function(e) {
    let angle = e.detail.data[0].directionFromOrigin;
    if ((angle >= 315 && angle <= 360) || (angle <= 45 && angle >= 0)) {
        (e.detail.events).forEach(_e => _e.originalEvent.preventDefault());
        window.location = "/'.$p.'";
        return;
    }
    else if (angle >= 135 && angle <= 225) {
        (e.detail.events).forEach(_e => _e.originalEvent.preventDefault());
        window.location = "/'.$n.'";
        return;
    }
});
</script>';
```

Works as expected on my Windows 10 machine and on my Android Phone.

#### Acknowledgement

As seen, this `ZingTouch` library is just great.

Documentation is fine for general insight, but sparse with respect to solutions of real problems, so I could not find out myself how to implement what I wanted.

I did not want to take the pain to read the source code, but rather thought about opening an issue. So I looked at what issues they already had.

From their issues I learned that `ZingTouch` had been abandoned, but has been revived recently. So kudos to **whoacowboy** as well.

Maybe some more working examples would be fine for people like me who only rarely deal with these topics.

#### Addendum

The working version showing traces of my finding process may be interesting for some, too:

```
echo '
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zingtouch/1.0.6/zingtouch.min.js" integrity="sha512-HmaXasRYOQJEXJWYwYCMcIA/XnPtW9WPvaBVWE2mQP6K31sRdcgaYUyB//P5540J4hFqMBcj6vkDEEGkwHkYdA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
//console.log("swipe_single");
var zt = new ZingTouch.Region(document.body);
//console.log("swipe_single2");
var myElement = document.getElementById("swipe_here");
//console.log("swipe_single3");

/*
zt.bind(myElement, "swipe", function(e){
        console.log(e.detail);
//        window.location = "/'.$p.'";
        //Actions here
}, false);
//console.log("swipe_single4");
*/

zt.bind(myElement, "pan", function(e) {
//  console.log("panning");

    let angle = e.detail.data[0].directionFromOrigin;

    if ((angle >= 315 && angle <= 360) || (angle <= 45 && angle >= 0)) {
        direction = "right";
        (e.detail.events).forEach(_e => _e.originalEvent.preventDefault());
        window.location = "/'.$p.'";
//console.log(direction);        
        return;
    }
    else if (angle >= 135 && angle <= 225) {
        direction = "left";
        (e.detail.events).forEach(_e => _e.originalEvent.preventDefault());
        window.location = "/'.$n.'";
//console.log(direction);        
        return;
    }
    else if (angle <= 135) {
        direction = "up";
//console.log(direction);        
    } else {
        direction = "down";
//console.log(direction);        
    }
});

console.log("swipe_single5");
</script>
';
```